# Looking for a proper math notation

Tags: notation, real-numbers

I am not a math persona so am not familiar with proper mathematical notations.

I am trying to define a function $f(\cdot)$ whose domain is a set of binary numbers $\mathbb{B}=[0,1]$ and range is a finite set of real numbers.

I am looking for an expression like one below

\begin{equation}
f(\cdot):\mathbb{B}\rightarrow\mathbb{?}\subset\mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

What should I put on left side of arrow that conveys that it is a finite set.

Comment: Why not $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: remember range and domain are not the same. So you could use  $f:\mathbb B\rightarrow \mathbb R$

Comment: Perhaps you want to consider maps with arbitrary but finite range? Then you could write "$f:\mathbb{B}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\operatorname{im} f$ is finite".

Comment: Also, you might want to write $\Bbb B = \{0, 1\}^n$ for the set of all binary numbers with $n$ digits. As it's written, your $\Bbb B$ just looks like the interval $\{r \in \Bbb R: 0 \le r \le 1\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just say

> $f: \mathbb{B} \to X$, where $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a finite set of reals.

Comment: $X$ is a closed or open one ?

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis It doesn't matter, although in the Euclidean topology all finite nonempty sets are closed and not open.

Comment: $X$ is a closed set